# Copy one2many field SNAFU

Tags: odoo

I need to show record from notebook project on notebook sheet , but the showed record is not according to project

My py :

```
class notebook_project(osv.osv):
    _name = "notebook.project"
    _description = "Notebook Project ID"

    def onchange_project(self, cr, uid, ids, project, arg, context=None):
        if project :
            proj = self.pool.get('project.project').browse(cr, uid, project, context=context)
            return {'value': {'name': proj.name}}
        return {}
    _columns = {
        'name' : fields.char('Name', size=64),
        'project' : fields.many2one('project.project', 'Project'),
        'notebook_project_lines' : fields.one2many('notebook.project', 'notebook_project_id', 'Members Lines'),
        'notebook_project_id': fields.many2one('notebook.project', 'Parent Project', ondelete='cascade', select=True),
        'member' : fields.many2one('hr.employee', 'Members'),

        }

notebook_project()


class notebook_sheet(osv.osv):
    _name = "notebook.sheet"
    _description = "Notebook Project Sheet"

    def onchange_notebook_project(self, cr, uid, ids, notebook_project, context=None):
        res = {}
        employee_lines = []
        if not notebook_project : return {}
        if notebook_project :
            notebook_project_obj = self.pool.get('notebook.project').browse(cr, uid, notebook_project)
            for p in notebook_project_obj.notebook_project_lines:
            employee_lines.append((0,0,{'notebook_sheet_lines':p.id
            }))#this dict contain keys which are fields of one2many field 
            res['notebook_sheet_lines']=employee_lines
            return res

    def onchange_project(self, cr, uid, ids, project, context=None):
        if project :
            proj = self.pool.get('project.project').browse(cr, uid, project, context=context)
            return {'value': {'name': proj.name}}
        return {}

    #def create(self, cr, user, vals, context={}):
    #first model
    #   notebook_project_obj = self.pool.get('notebook.project')
    #browse and get o2m fields, according to your selected project(id)
    #   notebook_project_lines = notebook_project_obj.browse(cr, user, ['notebook_project_id'])[0].lines
    #copy first o2m model to second o2m model
    #   for line in notebook_project_lines :
    #       vals['notebook_sheet_lines'].append([0, False, {'notebook_project_lines':line.employee_id.id,}])
    #   return super(notebook_sheet, self).create(cr, user, vals, context)

    _columns = {
        'name' : fields.char('Name', size=64),
        'notebook_sheet_lines' : fields.many2many('notebook.project', 'notebook_project_sheet_rel', 'notebook_project', 'notebook_project_id'),
        'notebook_project': fields.many2one('notebook.project', 'Project ID',domain=[('notebook_project_id','=',False)]),
        'project' : fields.many2one('project.project', 'Project'),
        'member' : fields.many2one('hr.employee', 'Members'),

        }

notebook_sheet()
```

Edited my answer , Mr. AnomA . Still not sure about many2many , please kindly check it

Do i need to change the onhange event as well ? thanks again in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all please create a link between notebook.sheet and notebook.project. Now there is no link between these 2 models. Add a many2one relation to notebook.sheet in notebook.project and then change the relation id in notebook_sheets_lines to this field.
Otherwise change the relation type of notebook_sheet_lines to many2many.
Then change the onchange_notebok_project() which will return `{'value':{'notebook_sheet_lines':LIST_OF_EMPOYEEIDS}}` 
Also No need to add many2many in motebook_project.

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer , I've tried it , but still no luck . It always shows employee from first project ( project A )

Comment: still failed , I think maybe the mistake is not the onchange but instead the relation between field in notebook.project itself ... what's your opinion Mr. AnomA ?

Comment: i cant find any mistake in it

Comment: So the relation itself is not mistaken ... any idea on how to show employee according to its project ? should i override the create function maybe ?

Comment: Should i add many2many on notebook.project as well ? If yes , which fields that have many2many ?